# I never have an Authenticated user using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

I am making my app with laravel but I never run make:auth or migrate because I alredy have a database in mysql and it already has data and my table for user it is "usuarios", so this is the code that I use to log in:

```
  public function store(){
        //intento de iniciar session


        $request=request(['usuario','password']);


        if(!auth()->attempt($request)){

                return redirect('/');
        }

        //redirigir a donde se necesite

        if(User::getCliente($request['usuario'])==0){

            return redirect('/staff');

        }

        return redirect('/cliente');

    }

    public function destroy(){

        auth()->logout();
        return redirect('/');

    }

    public function prueba(){

        $user = \DB::table('usuarios')->get();

        return $user;

    }
```

and it let me in and redirects me to the route that it is suposse to Authenticated user, but it is like I stay as a guest because nothing of Auth work, and when I use Auth::check() is like if there is not a Authenticated user, so if it was an attempt to be Authenticated I do not get why does not work.

Comment: You should really use Laravel's authentication system. I'm pretty sure your probably not that far along in whatever it is your coding and if you are... then still start fresh install of laravel and run art make:auth and move your old code over.  ;)

Comment: @cmac I try to do it but it is really hard to make the changes that I need because my table 'usuarios' is really diferent that user, so if I make it laravel's way It makes me work with that table, for example I do not need an email, because a lot of of my users doesn't even have one (some of them are people from the country) so I don't think laravel's way would help me this time

Answer (score 0):

@cmac is right.Use laravel's authentication system. If your username is not email you can easily do the following.

in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php add the following method to override the default username

```
public function username()
{
        return 'usuario';
}
```

and then to use the usuario table for users model simple go to your app/User.php Model and add the property to modify the table

```
protected $table = 'usuario';
```

The above is made on the assumption you are using the latest version of Laravel.

Comment: I did what you said but still does not work, what I do not get is that the auth()->attemp() is working, so if it does not get into that if then is supposed to be an auth user, am I rigth?